# Disabling Multidimensional Arrays for $_POST Inputs

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

We have the following code:

```
$_POST = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$comment = $_POST['comment'];
$comment = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($email));
```

After running a security scan (Acunetix) we have run into a problem.

If somebody was to modify the input variable `$_POST['comment']` and turn it into a longer array (possible called a multidimensional array), we get the following error message:

`strip_tags() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given...`

How can we disable the user from modifying the variable and just only accept the `$_POST['comment']` as a single string?

Comment: why not just use a prepared statement instead? Either with MySQLi_ or PDO, something you should be moving to in this century.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Fred, but this is what we are working with at the moment.  Can you offer any help to the above question?

Comment: You're welcome. Well since you are using an escape function, why the need to use `strip_tags()`? There's a particular sequence to follow here. If it's being treated as an array, then your inputs are not setup as arrays, far as I can see. I might be missing something here though or not grasping the question.

Comment: You could test `$_POST['comment']` with `is_array()` *before* sending it to the escape function.

Comment: I've updated the code above to show a better example - "email" was a bad example as we can use other functions (filter_var) for that.  We are using strip tags because we don't want users from inputting HTML in their comments.  We are getting the error message when a user modifies the input fields and POSTing them to make them multidimensional arrays (I think that's what they are called).  We want to stop users from creating these "multidimensional arrays" or perhaps you guys have another suggestion about getting around this (without switching to mysqli/PDO)?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jay.  That's a good idea - and we could unset `$_POST['comment']` if an array is detected?

Comment: It's redundant to use `strip_tags` if you are using `FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING`.

Comment: @TedWilmont I pulled in one of the best logical thinkers I know here (Jay) ;-) since I couldn't wrap my head around it. Good question too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to test the variable to see if it contains an array. Using a conditional check it would look something like this:

```
if(is_array($_POST['comment'])){
    unset($_POST['comment'])
} else {
    $comment = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($comment));
}
```

In this case, based on the OP's comment concerning un-setting the variable if it contains an array, I have used the `unset()` function in the ternary. If it is just a string then it is passed to the variable `$comment`.

Comment: Jay, dropping that code in directly didn't work: `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'unset' (T_UNSET)`  Also, could we incorporate an `isset` on the `$_POST['comment']`? - that way it wouldn't be setting $comment if it's empty.

Comment: You may have to use the longer version of an `if` statement. Let me test. And yes - you can incorporate an `isset()`.

Comment: My primitive coding skills have come up with: `if (isset($_POST['comment'])){
if ($is_array($_POST['comment'])) {
unset($_POST['comment']);
}
else {
$comment = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($comment));
}
}`  Is there a shorthand version for this?

Comment: I was trying to give you a shorthand version, but the `unset()` is problematic in a ternary because it is a PHP language construct. You'll have to use your longer code, which is fine.